# Date in Batch apex query

Tags: apex, soql, batch

I am writing an Batch apex where I need to query the records which are created today(System date). 
I created one field name `Created_Date_Formatted__c` which just gives me only date from `CreateDate` field.
In my start(Database.BatchableContext BC) method, I am passing my query as string

`query ='SELECT id,name FROM sObject__c WHERE Created_Date_Formatted__c = '+ String.valueOf(System.now());`

I have records which has created_Date_format__c as today, When I am querying the records in query editor without any where clause it gives me all the records
[image]

But when I copy the date(red marked) and put the where clauses it does not work
[image]

I have tried putting date in different format but it doesn't work. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me. Please let me know if anything else is also required from my side. I will update the thread.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around the date?

Comment: yes it throws error. `Created_Date_Formatted__c FROM sobject__c WHERE Created_Date_Formatted__c = '2017-08-09' ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:65 value of filter criterion for field 'Created_Date_Formatted__c' must be of type date and should not be enclosed in quotes`

Comment: why are you creating text fields for date, it should be date field

Comment: Created_Date_Formatted__c is Date type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a formula like this. You'll end up needing a full table scan every time you run this query, which will easily time out on larger tables. Instead, you can literally just say "today" in your query:

```
return Database.getQueryLocator([
  SELECT Id FROM SObject__c WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY
]);
```

"TODAY" automatically selects all records created from midnight local time (according to the user's time zone). If you want records from the last 24 hours, you can calculate that, too:

```
DateTime twentyFourHoursAgo = System.now().addHours(-24);
return Database.getQueryLocator([
  SELECT Id FROM SObject__c WHERE CreatedDate >= :twentyFourHoursAgo
]);
```

When you absolutely need to filter on a formula that returns text, you still need to quote the value:

```
SELECT Created_Date_Formatted__c FROM SObject__c 
WHERE Created_Date_Formatted__c = '2017-08-09'
```

Comment: Where I can found the documentation of Database.getQuerySelector()?

Comment: @LetMeCodeYou It doesn't exist, it was a typo (that was copy-pasted). It's getQueryLocator.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this work if your **Created_Date_Formatted__c** field is a **Date** Type

```
query ='SELECT id,name FROM sObject__c WHERE Created_Date_Formatted__c = today'
```

You can also use Standard field to get result by **creadteDate**. Date and time when this record was created. CreatedDate fields have Defaulted on create and Filter access.

```
query ='SELECT id,name FROM sObject__c WHERE DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) = 2005-10-08
```

or

```
 query ='SELECT id,name FROM sObject__c WHERE DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) = today
```

To filter a SOQL query on a datetime field with a day value, use the **DAY_ONLY** SOQL operator.

Comment: Created_Date_Formatted__c is type Date type only.

Comment: Then above soql should work for you.

Comment: Created_Date_Formatted__c is custom date  field you created ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
`query ='SELECT id,name FROM sObject__c WHERE Created_Date_Formatted__c = today'` worked.

Comment: Your welcome....

Comment: Don't forget to vote if it worked .

Comment: yes voted. but due to less reputation it will not be visible to public :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this using workbench ? I just checked at my end its works fine. Please make sure in your case, `Created_Date_Formatted__c` is of Date data type.

[image]